# Are there any constants other than $\pi$ that give rational or known irrational values for $\cos(\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

For example:

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{1}{2}$

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Is there any other constant $\theta$ such that $\cos(k\theta)$ is rational or a known irrational where $k$ is not $0$ or something trivial like $\frac{\pi}{\theta}$?

Comment: what about $\theta=1$? Is this relevant? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann-Weierstrass_theorem What counts as known?

Comment: How about $\theta=\arctan(2)$ and $k=1$?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by known constant. Are imaginary numbers allowed? Cosine takes all values on $[-1,1]$; so any number, rational, irrational, or transcendental, that is on that interval, has a corresponding angle that would satisfy your question. Are values produced from inverse trigonometric functions allowed? For example, $\theta=\arctan(n)$ gives $\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$, which is rational or irrational for integer values of $n$. Is that a known constant?

Comment: @rajb245 Sorry, I meant any number that is known to be irrational. I have not worked with the imaginary unit in trigonometric functions. The example you gave is interesting. I did not know that before.

Comment: Here is a constant number: $\arctan(10)$. It's cosine is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{101}}$, which is a known irrational number. My question is, does the number $\arctan(10)$ qualify as a "constant", by your definition?

Comment: What's more, $\cos(2\arctan(10))=\frac{-99}{101}$ and $\cos(\arctan(10)/2)$ has a closed forms in terms of radicals. There are tons of forms like this if the outputs of inverse trig functions are considered constants.

Comment: @rajb245 Yes those kinds of constants was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reasonable reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants

To quote:
"According to Niven's theorem, the only rational values of the sine function for which the argument is a rational number of degrees are 0, 1/2, and 1."

Doing a search for
"rational values of cosine"
produced this result 
and many other useful references.